# MailTo: Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp label that I need to be able to change according to the code behind.  How can I do this?

ASPX:  (The first part works correctly only for "TestA@abc.com" and the second part dynamically changes the label (EmailLabel) according to the "if" statement in the code behind.  How can I integrate these two so the label is mailto? Thanks.

```
<p>Email at <a href="mailto:TestA@abc.com?subject=Comments">TestA@abc.com</a>.</p>

<p>Email at <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>.</p>
```

Code Behind:

```
public changeLabel()
{
 if (//Some Condition Here)
 {
    this.EmailLabel.Text = "TestA@abc.com";
 }
 else
 {
  this.EmailLabel.Text = "TestB@abc.com";
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make this label clickable (like the first `<a>` tag)?

Comment: I have a method that populates the the EmailLabel with different email addresses.  Yes, I would like to be able to make it clickable (mailto:). hanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do there won't work.  Label's render out as `<span>` tags, so it will never be "clickable".  You want to do something more like this:

```
<p>Email at <a href="mailto:TestA@abc.com?subject=Comments">TestA@abc.com</a>.</p>

<p>Email at <asp:LinkButton ID="EmailLabel" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>.</p>
```

And then instead of changing the `Text` property, change the `NavigateUrl` property.

You could also use an [`HtmlControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is basically a standard HTML tag that you add the `runat="server"` attribute to.

```
<p>Email at <a id="EmailLabel" runat="server" href=""></a>.</p>
```

You would then be able to modify this `<a>` tag via server side code, the properties will be slightly different, but now you've got a real live anchor tag to work with.

This other SO question might also be helpful: [How to launching email client on LinkButton click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804384/how-to-launching-email-client-on-linkbutton-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<span id="foo" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'never say never'"
>
    Click Me!
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

For your Label, just remember that .Text is the server equivalent of .innerHTML so you can put whatever HTML you want right into the asp:Label when setting .Text.  Just watch out for cross-site-scripting exploits.