# Launching Client Email with ASP value with LinkButton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This one has been giving me trouble all morning and I hope someone with more ASP knowledge can help me!  I didn't build this app, I inherited it and it was built in .NET 2.0.

I'm upgrading an app that generated a list of href=mailto.  Now it needs to run some C# code so I started recreating these as linkButtons.  I was following this article [How to launching email client on LinkButton click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804384/how-to-launching-email-client-on-linkbutton-click-event?lq=1) but I have one more step.

```
<asp:Repeater DataSourceID="sdsUserList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' OnClientClick="window.open('mailto:<%# Eval("UserEmail") %>', 'email')" OnClick="lblEmail_Click" />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I need the OnClientClick to simply open up a new email to send to the User.  I've monkeyed around with the quotes but the error I am getting is "The server tag is not well formed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the quotes for your OnClientClick. You'll need to change this:

```
OnClientClick="window.open('mailto:<%# Eval("UserEmail") %>', 'email')"
```

You could try calling a function with the Eval statement as a parameter. For example:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return SendEmail(\"{0}\")", Eval("UserEmail").ToString()) %>'

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendEmail(email){
        window.open("mailto:" + email);
    }

</script>
```

I think there are other ways to escape the quotes too, but that's just a possible quick fix. This I just tested and it works fine. Good luck!

Comment: I tried that same quote combination but it didn't work.  I'll try the SendEmail.  Thanks!

Comment: I made and edit to clarify the change.  I can test now as well to check

Comment: Further edit, which is now tested.  Got help from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter